# Behavior of String in C#

Tags: c#

I am a C++ programmer, now working on a C# project.

I am trying to understand in the below snippet why the value of string does not change even though the function is changing its value, I thought it is an object and would be passed as a reference.

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass(String passedStr)
        {
            passedStr = "Change me";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String aString="I am what i am";
            TestClass obj = new TestClass(aString);
            Console.WriteLine(aString);

        }
    }
```

But behavior with user defined classes are different.

```
 public class TestClass
    {
        private int x;
        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return x;
            }
            set
            {
                x = value;
            }
        }
        public TestClass(int a)
        {
            x = a;
        }
    }
    public class Tester
    {
        public Tester(TestClass obj)
        {
            obj.ID = 999;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TestClass obj = new TestClass(555);
            Tester tester = new Tester(obj);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's passed by value; there's no `ref` keyword.

It's passing a *reference type* (here, a class) **by value** (no `ref` keyword), just like passing a copy of a pointer in C++. You're reassigning the pointer, not the actual data (which you can't do with strings anyway).

If you need pass-by-reference, try:

```
    public TestClass(ref String passedStr)
    {
        passedStr = "Change me";
    }

    ...
    TestClass obj = new TestClass(ref aString);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, If i take my own written class. I see i need not to write ref in argument type. it takes reference by default. what is special case with String

Comment: @sat: There's nothing special with `String` in this regard -- would you mind posting code showing what you mean by "my own written class"?

Comment: @sat: Yes, you are passing a reference. However, you are not changing the *contents* of the reference, you're making the (local) reference point to another string literal. See my answer for an example in C, which might be more familiar to you.

Comment: @sat: The difference is that string is actually a primitive in C#.  Primitives are passed by value and objects are passed by reference.  So when you pass a string, you're passing a string primitive by value and when you pass your own object, you're passing an object by reference.

Comment: @sat: Your code assigns to `obj.ID`, not `obj`. The C++ equivalent would be `obj->ID = ...` which is clearly different from `obj = ...`. If `String.Length` wasn't read-only, it would have behaved the same way.

Comment: @Mehrdad I think OP is trying to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866187/behavior-of-string-in-c/5866623#5866623

Answer (score 6):

Let's go back to basics.

A variable is a storage location.

A variable of type string is a storage location that stores either null, or a reference to a string.

"passedStr" and "aString" are *different variables*.

When you call "new TestClass(aString)" you create a new storage location for "passedStr" and copy the contents of "aString" into it. You now have two variables that have the same content: a reference to a string.

Inside the constructor you change the value stored in the storage location for "passedStr".  "aString" remains the same.

The "ref" and "out" keywords in C# mean "make the formal parameter and the argument *aliases* of each other". In that case you have only *one* variable with *two different names*. When you change one of them the other one changes as well, because they are the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are passed by reference but the pointer is passed by value in C#. If you want to pass the string by reference you'll have to make use of the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) key word.

For example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass(ref string passedStr)
    {
        passedStr = "Change me";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string aString="I am what i am";
        TestClass obj = new TestClass(ref aString);
        Console.WriteLine(aString); // "Change me"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`passedStr` is not the string, but a constructor parameter that holds a reference to the string.  All your `TestClass` constructor is doing is changing the string that this parameter references.  It has no effect outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the constructor, is that you are assigning a *new* String literal to the local variable `passedStr`.

In C, the equivalent function would look something like this:

```
Testclass constructor_testclass(char* passedStr) {
    passedStr = "Change me";
}
```

I think it's obvious that this function does not change the value of the `char*` in the *calling* function.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks, I'll remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The object `I am what i am` is being passed by reference, but the reassignment is to a local variable. You don't change the original object, but instead assign a new object (`Change me`) to the location of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Employee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID = {0} Name = {1}", ID, Name);
    }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public TestClass2(Employee e)
    {
        e.ID="007";
        e.Name="james";
    }
}  



static void Main()
{

    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.ID = "0";
    e.Name = "nobody";
    TestClass2 t = new TestClass2(e);
    Console.WriteLine(e); //Output ID = 007 Name = James 
}
```

strings are passed by reference but the pointer is passed by value in C#

[Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)